# Find file with specific text in folder

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I am trying to loop through all the files in a folder and get the path of one that contains a specific part of text. The text is not always in the same position and the folder is a network folder.
What would be the fastest way to do this in a network folder that contains hundreds of files with more than 30Mb each?

The `Dir()` solution did not work as it says "Bad file name or number" (Error 52). I am referencing the network path as `\\thisisthefolder\anotherfolder\`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop through files in a folder using VBA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380312/loop-through-files-in-a-folder-using-vba)

Comment: File size doesn't matter if you just want to find the file in the folder.

Comment: Is the text in question part of the file name or is it something that occurs in the file itself? If the latter, are these files text files? xlsx files? Also -- I am adding a VBScript tag to your question since I suspect that the optimal answer involves File System Objects, and any VBScript solution is easily run from VBA.

Comment: The `Dir()` solution did not work as it says "Bad file name or number" (Error 52). I am referencing the network path as `\\thisisthefolder\anotherfolder`

Comment: Just add \ to the end of the folder string so it should be \thisisthefolder\anotherfolder\

Comment: I got it! I had to add \ by the end of the string